# How to register or make available a manually unzipped package to other packages in julia?

Tags: package, julia

Sorry, if I am wrong or silly!
I am new to Julia and trying to install package offline on CentOS 7.4, as follows:
a) downloaded julia binary package version 1.1.0 and unzipped to `/opt/julia`
b) downloaded  *ColorTypes.jl-master.zip,  FixedPointNumbers.jl-master.zip,  Reexport.jl-master.zip,  Colors.jl-master.zip* to /tmp folder and unzipped them.
c) And copied content to folders *ColorTypes,  FixedPointNumbers,   Reexport,  Colors* inside the folder, `/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/` respectively.
d) set environment variables:

```
export JULIA_HOME=/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0
export JULIA_LOAD_PATH=/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1
export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1
export PATH=$JULIA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

e) invoked julia

```
[julia@srvr1 ~]$julia
```

f) at julia prompt, invoked command, `using <PACKAGE_NAME>` where *<PACKAGE_NAME>* is from file, REQUIRES of Colors to precompile them and were successful except Colors.

```
julia>using ColorTypes
[ Info: Precompiling ColorTypes [top-level]
julia>using FixedPointNumbers
[ Info: Precompiling FixedPointNumbers [top-level]
julia>using Reexport
[ Info: Precompiling Reexport [top-level]
julia>using Colors
[ Info: Precompiling Colors [top-level]
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package FixedPointNumbers [53c48c17-4a7d-5ca2-90c5-79b7896eea93] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.
```

Please guide me in:
 
a) registering the package FixedPointNumbers to make available to its dependent packages
(or)
b) getting the required FixedPointNumbers, if any version mismatch
(or)
c) configuration changes to use the available version of FixedPointNumbers, if any version mismatch!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to use packages is using Julia's builtin tools (see [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.1/stdlib/Pkg/))

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("ColorTypes")
Pkg.add("FixedPointNumbers")
Pkg.add("Reexport")
Pkg.add("Colors")
```

Comment: Whether local downloaded package path can be passed on as argument Pkg.add()? Whether adding entries to project.toml, manifest.toml will help?